# Relationship not found between Marketing Lists and Emails Sends - Clickdimensions CRM 2015

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015, exacttarget, clickdimension

We have clickdimensions installed in a 2015 CRM version. This environment previously used Exact Target for email marketing automation. We removed Exact Target before upgrading from 2011 -> 2013 -> 2015.

Whenever any user attempts to associate an email send to a marketing list, they get the following error:

The Relationship with Name = 'cdi_emailsend_list' was not found in the MetadataCache

The interesting part is that the relationship does exist. In the entity section of 'Customizations', an N:N relationship exists between the two entities and is present on both the 'Email Send' and 'Marketing List' screen. In the CRM database, we've also been able to find the relationship and the intersect table. All fields appear correct when we compare them to another entity having an N:N relationship with Marketing Lists.

From the traces of the error, we get more detail:

Stack Trace Info: [RelationshipMetadataNotFoundException: The Relationship with Name = 'cdi_emailsend_list' was not found in the MetadataCache] 
at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.ServerDynamicMetadataCache.GetRelationship(String name) 
at Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AssociateRecords.AssociateOneToMany(Int32 childType, Guid childId, Int32 parentType, Guid parentId, String relationshipName)

This would seem to indicate that CRM is looking for a one to many relationship rather than a N:N relationship.

We've tried removing and reinstalling the solution. That didn't have an effect on the error.

We've also spun up other CRM environments (2015 online and on-prem) and imported the Clickdimensions solutions into those environments. Those environments have no issue associating email sends to marketing lists. So, we've narrowed it down to an environment-specific issue.

Does anyone have any recommendations for next steps or what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My strong suggestion - get in touch with ClickDimensions support to clarify what's happening.